# Why is the resonant frequency changed and not the wavelength in the case of rising temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

If you play an instrument with a chamber, the standing wavelengths are created by the size of the chamber. When playing this instrument in a hotter area the temperature causes the resonant frequency to rise, so you get a higher sound.  This is due to the higher speed of sound caused by hotter air.

But in most cases when the speed is accelerated, for example when sound waves enter a faster medium like hotter air, not the frequency is going up but the wavelengths are getting shorter and this also gives a higher sound.

But why, in case of hotter air, does the resonant frequency go up instead of the wavelengths?

Answer (score 1):

What happens to musical instruments as the temperature charges depends on the musical instrument and there are many, many internet sites with information about particular instruments.

In your example the wavelength of the sound produced $\lambda$  is determined by the length of the chamber and that length changes very little with a change of temperature compared with the change in the speed of sound in air $c$ which increases with temperature.

$f \; \lambda = c$ where $f$ is the frequency of the sound wave so if the wavelength (fixed by the dimensions of the chamber) does not change very much and the speed of sound in air increases so does the frequency of the sound.

For string instruments the dominant effect is the decrease in string tension when the temperature increases leading to the frequency of oscillation of the strings decreasing.  Note that in this case the primary source of sound is the string vibrating whereas with your chamber it was the air vibrating.

Comment: That is strange, that for chamber instruments the frequency goes up where for string instruments the frequency goes down. Why is that? You say that the wavelength changes though a bit, but are they getting longer or shorter?

Comment: For the chamber because it expands very little as the temperatures rises the wavelength of the sound in the air increases a little.  For a string instrument with an increase in the temperature the frequency of the string and hence of the sound wave in air has gone down and the speed of sound in air has increase the wavelength of the sound in the air increases quite significantly.

Comment: So as the frequencies dictate mostly whether a sound is high or low, with increasing temperature a violin would sounds lower but a didgeridoo would sound higher?

Comment: Can you tune a didgeridoo?

Comment: Perhaps you can't tune it (unless you go rase it) but with increasing temperature the resonant frequency raise.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the resonant frequency in an instrument is determined by the length of the chamber and the speed of the sound wave.  Let's say that the speed of sound at 20° C is 343 m/s, and we have an instrument that behaves like an open pipe which is 0.6 m long. Open pipes resonate at the frequency whose wavelength is twice the length of the pipe and all whole number multiples of that frequency.  So it will resonate at a frequency whose wavelength is 1.2 m.  That frequency is 343 / o.6 = 572 Hz.  So we say that 572 Hz is the resonate frequency.  Now let's say that the temperature rises to 40°C.   The speed of sound increases to 355 m/s.  Now the wavelength of the 572 Hz wave is 0.62 m.  That's too long to resonate.  It's still in the chamber bouncing around with many, many other waves produced by the lips or reed, but it is no longer the resonant frequency.   A 592 Hz wave (355 / 0.6) that was already in there is the new resonant frequency.  So we say "the resonant frequency has changed," But no waves have changed frequency, they have change wavelength, just as you thought.

Comment: But why must the resosonant frequency change and not the wavelength? Usually when the speed of the medium gets higher only the wavelengthe get longer but not the frequency but why isn't that here the case?

Comment: Ok, do I understand you right that wavelength ánd frequency is changed? But if the frequency is higher and also the speed, becomes the wavelength shorter or longer?

Comment: You say no frequencies change but you are also talking about a new frequency that is confusing.

Comment: @Marijn, I have deleted my previous comments and revised my original answer.  I hope that it is clear.